Not loading static(CSS,JS,BOOTATRAP) files after applying "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"
I am working on django website,i made some changes in jquery file and then apply  "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" in browser ,but now all the static files are not reflecting in browser, before clearing the cache all the files were working properly,
What should be the issue here and how can I solve this
I am unable to find the issue ,i don't think that the issue with any url, static or location of files as they were working properly before applying "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" ,and the error in console is "404" for all the static files like "
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:19 
        
        
       GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

"
# settings.py
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Category',
    'accounts',
    'store',
    'cart',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',index,name='index'),
    path('store/',include('store.urls')),
    path('cart/',include('cart.urls')),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# base.html
{% load static%}

<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<!-- Font awesome 5 -->
<link href="{% static 'fonts/fontawesome/css/all.min.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


Your django dev instance does not have a urlpattern for serving static files. Update your urlspatterns.py to include the static function with reference to the static folder as in your settings.py.
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',index,name='index'),
    path('store/',include('store.urls')),
    path('cart/',include('cart.urls')),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
] + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
) + static(
    settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT
)

Without this django cannot route the requests for static files to the correct path.
In a production app you would normally offload this work to nginx or another webserver. When in dev, you are asking django to "proxy" the request and serve the static assets itself.

You don't need to configure the URL for static files in development as long as you have django.contrib.staticfiles in the INSTALLED_APPS setting. The issue is probably either that they haven't configured the static directory to be in STATICFILES_DIRS or that their paths are wrong.

@AbdulAzizBarkat paths are not wrong as the files were working good before clearing the cache, after clearing the cache I just refresh the page and the only thing that remian on page was HTML content and nothing else

And you are sure that the value of STATIC_ROOT is a valid path on your machine and that the static folder hasn't changed position in the tree

yeah sure about it, no changes in tree,static folder is in base directory and and css,js are in this static folder and accessing the files like this "
